NullInjectorError and app.module.ts does nothing
(Using Angular 18)
I'm trying to make an HTTP request from a component and I'm getting a NullInjectorError regarding _HttpClient. In my component, I'm importing it, instantiating it in the constructor, and calling it correctly.
app.module.ts also imports HttpClient and lists it in the imports array. I also tried importing HttpClientModule for good measure (even though my component doesn't use it.)
One bizarre detail is that when I created my project, app.module.ts was not created; I had to manually create the file. I think I put it in the right folder (src/app) but concerned that I may have failed to do something else, like add it to an index file or something, and perhaps this is causing Angular to completely ignore the module. I also notice that my app doesn't even rebuild when I modify app.module.ts; I have no indication it's being used at all.
Finally, I tried implementing this solution (Nullinjectorerror: no provider for httpclient! without app.module.ts) and the console prints out data which indicates the HTTP call is actually happening and returning data correctly, but the NullInjectorError still appears (the DOM also refuses to render, all I get is a white screen.) This makes no sense, how can it complain about a dependency not being there but then demonstrably make use of that dependency?
I tried creating app.modules.ts and importing HttpClient, the exact same error appeared as if I had done nothing.

please share the github repo or mode code!

Nowadays by default is an standalone app,
Take a look to create ng new with the app.module.ts file feauture.
My own response
In that case, as standalone application you should have a file which bootstrap the application,
the main.ts file
At this file you should provide the provider of provideHttpClient:
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [provideHttpClient()],
})

or usually we have define an external file named app.config.ts with any provider and other stuff.
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)

